# Nuclear Physics - Atomic discovery and radiation

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radiation, radioactivity, ionization-energy

Why do different forms of nuclear radiation have different ionising abilities?

- I understand that alpha, beta and gamma rays are all composed differently, and that they have different ionising abilities due to the loss of energy as they interact with other particles, but what dictates these different ionising abilities?

What protection is provided in radiation use?

- I understand why short life isotopes are used for tracers as they need to work quickly; however, how are radioactive substances with a long life used?

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What are your suggestions as answer to your questions which can be found very easily in textbooks and the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many question--nevertheless, I'll take nuclear radiation. $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ radiation have different ionizing potentials because they are different particles. Let's take the 1st two: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ radiation. These are charged particles, $^4$He and $e^-$, respectively. Charged particles interact with atomic electrons, and lose energy as they pass through matter interacting with atoms along the way--a processes triumphantly described by the Bethe-Bloch equation:
$
-\langle\frac{dE}{dx}\rangle=\frac{4\pi}{m_e\ c^2}\cdot
\frac{nz^2}{\beta^2}
(\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\ })^2
\cdot
[\ln{\frac{2m_ec^2\beta^2}{I\cdot(1-\beta^2)}-\beta^2}]
$

Comparing electrons to helium nuclei: the nuclei are much heavier, and hence slower than electrons with similar energy--and the $1/\beta^2$ term means they lose energy *much* faster than electrons do. There is also a factor of 4 coming from $z^2$. They can't penetrate a piece of tissue paper--they dump their energy immediately. They become dangerous when their sources are ingested and incorporated into tissue--locally radiating surrounding tissue.

Electron's are much more penetrating and dump their energy on a long path--hence the aluminum shielding. It provides lots of atomic electrons without too much mass. Note that high energy electrons undergo Bremsstrahlung in the nuclear field--and the square of the field strength near the nucleus matters. Hence lead shielding: lots of cheap, dense, high-Z nuclei.

$\gamma$-rays are photons. They are neutral so they don't ionize anything as they pass through matter; however, when they do interact, the interaction products are charged and *they* ionize. At low energy, the photo-electric effect dominates. At medium energy, it is Compton scattering. At higher energies, pair production--again, nuclear electric field strength squared matters, so lead shielding.

Let's not forget neutrons. They are neutral and do not ionize. Rather, they mostly scatter off nuclei. If that nuclei is lead, they retain most of their energy and continue on. If it is proton (of near equal mass to the neutron), the energy is split, and the proton is sent off to ionize, while the neutron does a "rinse and repeat"--ionizing along they way. In proton rich environments, such as the water filled human body, they do tremendous damage. Shielding is commonly paraffin--a proton loaded hydrocarbon. Add some neutron-absorbing boron, and it is an effective shield.

Nuclear decays can also emit neutrinos--but they don't interact much--and that's an understatement.

$\beta^+$, positrons, exist too--they ionize much like electrons, though there is the antimatter annihilation at the end.

Comment: I do not think that you should be giving such a detailed answer to a series of questions which show no evidence that the OP has done any research. By answering such questions you might encourage others to post "do my homework" requests without showing that they have made any prior effort.